# Activity fragment in expandable listview?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm looking for any examples or (even better) tutorials that can help me accomplish this.  But I keep coming up short in my google searches, which has me worried that it's not even possible.  So that's my first question:  Can an expandable listview inflate a fragment when it expands and call it's onDestroy when retracted?  and if so, can you please link me to any help with accomplishing this.  Thanks

Here's a little visual of what I'm looking to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first, the general UI paradigm could be handled with an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). whether this gives you enough to match exactly what you need is TBD.

as for having fragments inside the list ... theoretically, in the list view's adapter's `getView()` method, you could do a [`FragmentTransaction.replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29), passing in a container ID that exists in the inflated view. i have *not* tried this.

that being said, i seriously doubt this will work. list views are smart about managing views. the views in the list are often destroyed and re-created as the user scrolls the list. adding fragments to a view is an expensive operation.

as an alternative, you might consider a [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), which can hold fragments by design. it's not the UI you have spec'd above, but it's a common UI pattern used by many stock Google apps, so you know it's been tested.

Comment: I want it to load info from an SQLITE database and display it. It won't have any ongoing interaction other than expanding and displaying the data.  Still no good, you think?  Also, thanks very much for the ViewPager suggestion.  Although it won't work with what I'm doing here, after more reading on it, it looks like it wouldn't be too hard to implement and would give any app some nice eye candy.

Comment: i think the weight comes from the `Fragment` life cycle, not necessarily what's in list items. what's the reason you need the list items to be fragments? are they displaying data that is logically the same type?

Comment: yeah, they display static info from the sqlite database